# Python Selenium - Login Page Not Appearing

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to create a Python script that does the following:

1. Goes to this website: https://li-public.fmcsa.dot.gov/LIVIEW/pkg_html.prc_limain
2. Chooses the “Insurance Filing” option in the dropdown in the top right corner.
3. Clicks “Go” to advance to the next page.
4. Clicks the Accept button to advance to the new page.
5. Then inputs my log in information into the resulting login menu to log into the system.

(For the sake of anonymity, let’s say this is my login information:
username = ‘fake_username’
password = ‘fake_password’ )

I can do steps 1-4 perfectly fine, but I am struggling with step 5. The page you go to whenever you click the Accept button in Step 4 is blank and does not include the login menu, preventing me from then inputting my username and password. Any ideas on how to access the login menu?

Here is my Python code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get("https://li-public.fmcsa.dot.gov/LIVIEW/pkg_html.prc_limain")
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('menu'))   
select.select_by_visible_text('Insurance Filing')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@src='/lihtml/go.gif' and @type='image']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='        Accept        ']").click()
print(driver.page_source)
```

Output:

Notice that the output is a blank html page, not giving any access to login menu with which to fill in the username and password. Is there any way to address this?

Comment: there is no login page even if this is done manually , only a login allert

Comment: `https://testuser:testpassword@li-public.fmcsa.dot.gov/LILOGIN/pkg_warning.prc_check_user`

Comment: coulyou provid your username password like this and see if it works ?

Comment: Do you mean provide the username and password manually into that page? It does sign in when I do it manually (though of course I'd like the script to be able to do that).

Comment: does it work with username and password hard coded in the url ?

Comment: Yes, it does when hard coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get("https://li-public.fmcsa.dot.gov/LIVIEW/pkg_html.prc_limain")
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('menu'))   
select.select_by_visible_text('Insurance Filing')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@src='/lihtml/go.gif' and @type='image']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='        Accept        ']").click()
url=driver.current_url

url = "https://username:password@"+url.split("https://")[1]
driver.get(url)
```

try this code we are getting the current url and opening that url with the username password hardcoded ,

As the notification is browser level you cannot handle it with selenium

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most full answer based on a slight modification of PDHide's code (after doing his code, you'd have to renavigate to the given website since it dumps you back at the landing page automatically):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

 

from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

 

import time

 

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get("https://li-public.fmcsa.dot.gov/LIVIEW/pkg_html.prc_limain")
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('menu'))   
select.select_by_visible_text('Insurance Filing')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@src='/lihtml/go.gif' and @type='image']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='        Accept        ']").click()
url=driver.current_url

url = "https://put_username_here:put_password_here"+url.split("https://")[1]
driver.get(url)
#Renavigating to the page again having already logged in
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('menu')) 
select.select_by_visible_text('Insurance Filing')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@src='/lihtml/go.gif' and @type='image']").click()
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: swp1 what if you authenticate index page itself ? driver.get("https://username:password@li-public.fmcsa.dot.gov/LIVIEW/pkg_html.prc_limain")

Comment: Do you mean at the first get statement (driver.get("https://li-public.fmcsa.dot.gov/LIVIEW/pkg_html.prc_limain"))?

Comment: It doesn't log in properly when I do.